# System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast error

Tags: c#

I'm getting error at `Cast<DataRow>` saying that

```
 System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult (System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)' is a 'method`
```

Which is not valid in the given context.

Thanks for the help. Below is my code

```
StringBuilder sbTmp = new StringBuilder();
dtMessage.AsEnumerable().Cast<DataRow>.ToList.ForEach(x =>    sbTmp.AppendLine((x["SegmMessage"]).ToString()));
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the parentheses for invoking the `Cast` and `ToList` methods:

```
.....Cast<DataRow>().ToList()....
```

In C# you need to use parentheses to invoke the method and evaluate to its result.  Otherwise the compiler thinks you're trying to refer to the physical method *itself* in the code, not its result.